# Histogram and other statistical functions using vba

Tags: excel

I am trying to produce an Histogram using the adds option of the excel program. Instead of using a range of cells, I would like to use a variable which has 1000 different values. How can this be done?

To be more specific, I give you the relevant part of the code already written:

```
"Application.Run "ATPVBAEN.XLAM!Histogram", ActiveSheet.Range("$F$1:$F$10") _
, ActiveSheet.Range("$K$8"), , False, False, True, False.
```

On the above code, I would like to substitude the part `Range("$F$1:$F$10")` with a variable which gets 1.000 different values.

Comment: I don't know that this is possible. `ATPVBAEN.XLAM!Histogram` seems like it is a range-oriented sub. You could perhaps write the values into an out-of-the-way range (perhaps on a hidden sheet). Or -- ditch that entirely and find a way to create a bar chart to your liking. I have always found the analysis toolkit histograms to be on the ugly side.

Comment: Thanks for your answer !!! Please help me with another thing : how can write a part of a code that can transfer, say 100.000 values of a variable, into cells without spend a lot of time. I already have used the following routine   : " For i = 1 To 10 Step 1
m(i) = i
Cells(i, 6) = m(i)
Next i " but it takes hours to complete if the number of values are more than 10.000

Comment: Writing an array to a range should be done in a single line of code and take only seconds rather than hours. The basic template is `MyRange.Value = MyArray`. You have to make sure that the range has the right size. Also, it doesn't work as expected if `MyArray` is 1-dimensional and the range is a column range. In this case you need `MyRange.Value = Application.Transpose(MyArray)`. See [Arrays and Ranges in VBA](http://cpearson.com/excel/ArraysAndRanges.aspx) for a helpful blog post. See also [this](https://newtonexcelbach.com/2012/03/12/writing-arrays-to-the-worksheet-vba-function/)

Comment: you help me a lot. Many thanks !!!!

Comment: No problem. Hopefully next time I can actually answer the question rather than just point you in the right direction.